# Service account to send Docusign eSignature requests

Tags: docusignapi

I've signed up for a developer account with Docusign. We have about 15 users that access a Windows Forms page from another program where they fill out the proper information and click a button that calls a NET Core Web API which creates an envelope and sends to the signer. Those 15 users don't have accounts in Docusign and don't need them to. I want to use one admin or service account that will send and receive the emails, but I can't figure out how to do this.

I used my name for the developer account and now all my (test) Docusign emails show they are from me and once the signer signs, my email receives the signed documents. I've tried creating another "Admin" account, but I don't see any way to associate that user as an "API User". When I try using that user's GUID as the ImpersonatedUserID, my RequestJWTUserToken request comes back with "consent_required". But, when I go to the link I just get an error with "The client id provided is not registered with Docusign".

Everything in the Web API is working perfectly except for the emails showing they are from me and then the signed docs coming back to my email. This should be an easy thing to change the user, but apparently it's not, or I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on your way to fix this, but didn't follow through.

1. Create new user (you did it)
2. Find the new userId (you did)
3. Update `JRequestJWTUserToken` (you did)
4. Consent error - expected, the new user did not consent.
5. Obtain consent. You need to have a URL built correctly like this to do this:

https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature%20impersonation&client_id=7c2b8d7e-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-cda8a50dd73f&redirect_uri=http://example.com/callback/

Once you do 5, you need to log in with the same new user account you created (you may be automatically logged in with your original developer account, so log out) and provide consent.

Then step 4 will work just fine.

https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/consent/obtaining-individual-consent/

Comment: I had used the code that was included in the Quickstart app to generate the consent URL which added carets to the consent URL. Apparently the carets were the problem.

Comment: Sorry, we'll be fixing the carets, which language did you use? was it C#?

Comment: Yes, C#. I also had a problem after my app went into production. I kept getting the error "unexpected PEM type" when it was sending my private RSA key. In DSHelper.cs I had to change the code in the method "ReadFileContent" to "return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(File.ReadAllText(path));"

Comment: This is a completely different issue. Can you either ask another question and/or contact developer support?